# JSON.parse: bad escaped character with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am facing problem with json parse.
I have this in php:

```
 json_encode(getTeams(),JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

it return huge data.

Sample data:
for more clarification lets say i have this:

```
my_encoded_data = 
     {
        "13": "Germany-1",
        "14": "Russia-1",
        "15": "Switzerland-1",
        "16": "Canada-1",
        "17": "USA-1",
        "18": "USA-2",
        "19": "Germany-2",
        "20": "Italy-1",
        "21": "Switzerland-2",
        "22": "Austria-1",
        "23": "Italy-2",
        "24": "Netherlands-1",
        "25": "Poland-1",
        "26": "Latvia-1",
        "27": "Russia-2",
        "28": "Czech Republic-1",
        "29": "Great Britain-1",
        "30": "France-1",
        "31": "Canada-2",
        "32": "Slovakia-1",
        "43": "A. Florschütz/T. Wustlich",
        "44": "P. Leitner/A. Resch",
        "46": "G. Albrecht/E. Pothier",
        "48": "C. Moffat/M. Moffat",
        "50": "V. Boizov/D. Khamkin",
        "51": "M. Kuzmitch/J. Veselov",
        "53": "T. Schiegl/M. Schiegl",
        "56": "P. Griffal/D. Joye",
        "59": "A. Linger/W. Linger",
        "62": "G. Plankensteiner/O. Haselrieder",
        "65": "A. Sics/J. Sics",
        "68": "C. Oberstolz/P. Gruber"
    }
```

I have tested this data by spilt it into small parts to validate in jsonlint. it shows me valid json. 
then i have assigned it in javascript in:

```
window.objteamsFromServer  = my_encoded_data;
```

Then i wanted to parse it in json like this:

```
arrSearch = window.objteamsFromServer;
```

It gives me this error:

```
JSON.parse: bad escaped character
```

how can i solve this?

let me know if any informations needed .

Thanks,
Awlad

Comment: Where does `my_encoded_data` come from? What does the PHP code that generates the JavaScript code look like? (You seem to be using PHP to generate JavaScript.) What does your call to `JSON.parse` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to tell from your question exactly what `my_encoded_data` is, but it sounds as though you're outputting the result of `json_encode` into JavaScript source code, e.g. (from the browser's perspective):

```
window.objteamsFromServer = {
    "13": "Germany-1",
    "14": "Russia-1",
    "15": "Switzerland-1",
    "16": "Canada-1",
    "17": "USA-1",
    // ...and so on
};
```

and then *also* trying to parse it with `JSON.parse`.

You wouldn't do that. The JavaScript engine will have already parsed that object initializer (it's not JSON, it's JavaScript source code), so you would just use the value directly:

```
console.log(window.objteamsFromServer[13]); // "Germany-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be getting this error because of the following line:

```
"43": "A. Florschütz/T. Wustlich",
```

Notice the 'ü' in the name above.

One approach is to encode the data at server side and then decode it on client side.
Use JavaScripts decodeURIComponent function do decode at client side.

For server-side encoding of data, please refer php documentation.

Comment: There's no problem with the `ü` character in JavaScript (or JSON), provided the text is being read by the browser in the same encoding in which it was sent by the server.